# predicate for condition variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11, operating-system

I am new to multi threading.
While writing multi threaded code in C++11 using condition variable , I use the following construct

```
while(predicate) {
    cond_var.wait(&lock);
}
```

However, I have been reading Deitel's third edition book on operating systems(chp 6) where the following construct is being used

```
if(predicate) {
    cond_var.wait(&lock);
}
```

So, what's the difference? Why isn't the book using while? Isn't spurious call an issue?

Comment: FWIW, with C++11's condition variables you should simply use `cond_var.wait(lock, []{ return !predicate; });`

Comment: I think both using while or passing as an arg are equivalent. Quoting from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait/ If pred is specified (2), the function only blocks if pred returns false, and notifications can only unblock the thread when it becomes true (which is specially useful to check against spurious wake-up calls). This version (2) behaves as if implemented as:
 
while (!pred()) wait(lck);

Comment: You are right, you should loop to properly handle spurious wake-ups. Regarding concurrency in C++11 I would recommend Anthony William's "C++ Concurrency in Action".